# Indexing a sum of values by row from multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm struggling with this one...

[image]

In row 2 I have week numbers up to week 9 in this example. Row 1 has a formula that determines to which month a week belongs. In this example, week 5 is in month 1 and week 6 in month 2.

I need to sum the values by weeks and categories and show them in another table as monthly values as given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they can use "COUNTIF" because they want the sum of the cells.

This should work:

```
 =SUM(IF($B$1:$J$1=B$9,$B3:$J3,0))
```

entered in B10 through C14

This is an array formula so you have to enter the formula and then hit ctrl-shift-enter to enter the formula correctly.  It should show up as {=SUM(IF($B$1:$J$1=B$9,$B3:$J3,0))} in cell B10. The references will of course adjust when you copy and paste it into the other cells.

Enter the formula in cell B10 then copy and paste it into the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a sumif function that can be entered without using an array formula (and a sumifs that you don't need here)

In cell B10 you would enter

```
=sumif($B$1:$J$1,B$9,$B3:$J3)
```

this could be copied across and down to give you the sums that you need.